# Blackberry jumpy scroll

Tags: blackberry, scroll

I am having trouble with vertical scrolling on a blackberry app.
it works just fine on touch screens, but when scrolling using a track pad, it jumps from being at the top position to being at the bottom position.

Anyone had a similar problem? any idea what i could try?

Here is a snippet from my code. i have a static background image and the fields scroll on top of it:

```
vertical_main = new VerticalFieldManager(USE_ALL_WIDTH |NO_VERTICAL_SCROLL |USE_ALL_HEIGHT);
vertical_AllTags=new VerticalFieldManager(USE_ALL_WIDTH | VERTICAL_SCROLL);
// i then add all the fields to vertical_AllTags
vertical_main.add(vertical_AllTags);
vertical_main.invalidate();
add(vertical_main);
```

thanks in advance for your help

EDIT:
The suggestion of giving each field focus was correct. the only other part that needs to be done is when you override the onFocus method for a field, you need to call the super() function so that all the other normal parts of the onFocus method are still called:

```
protected void onFocus(int direction) {
    text_select=true;
    invalidate();
    super.onFocus(direction);
}

protected void onUnfocus() {
    text_select=false;
    invalidate();
    super.onUnfocus();
}
```

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is common issue in non touch devises for beginners. 
if you want to scroll field by field there is two ways

> 1) you need to give the focus to all fields then it will come field by
>   field focus down

another way is means you dont need to focus on each and every field

> 2)just add the NullField after your every field and give focus to all
>   NullFields then your trackball will bring your screen field by field

Comment: I was giving each field focus, but the problem was that i was overriding the onFocus method without calling the super(): [`code`](
protected void onFocus(int direction) {text_select=true;invalidate();super.onFocus(direction);}
protected void onUnfocus() {text_select=false;invalidate();super.onUnfocus();}) 

Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: welcome now is it working? if you have any doubts come this room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4014/knowledge-sharing-center-for-blackberry-and-java

Answer (score 1):

This happends beacuse in TrackWheel Scrolling it scrolls up to the next **Focused** field. I think you are not give any focus between the **vertical_AllTags**.

You can solved this by using **NullField()** class. Like...

```
add(new NullField(Field.FOCUSABLE))
```

when you add **add(new NullField(Field.FOCUSABLE));**  you will get the null focus which is not know by you. And you can navigate all the fields like Touch Screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve that issue by adding two vertical field manager.. take a look at the code in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8182670/913422)